# Execute the Playwright scripts from local machine, but it should execute on the Remote VM

Tags: playwright

I have on e remote machine on which I have installed all the required tools/softwares that needed to execute the Playwright script.

Now, my scenerio is I have the complete script written in my dev machine. I want that once I execute the my script, it should connect with my VM machine and then I should open chromium over there and perform every steps over there.

Comment: if you would like to execute your tests on a VM entirely then use a CI pipeline and checkout your code and execute your tests on that VM. The other approach is to use the docker image and run everything inside a container. https://playwright.dev/docs/docker. The other way is you can set a baseURL in your playwright.config.ts and refer to an .env

Comment: This should cover your scenario: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26482